# Buttons and OnClick Listener

Tags: android, button, onclick, listener

I am having 3 buttons on my layout. I want when each of it is pressed to go to a different screen. What I should do is something like this or something more complicated?

```
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      FirstButtonClicked();
}
});

b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    SecondButtonClicked();}
});

b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);
b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
ThirdButtonClicked();}
});
```

Must i return anything regarding the button pressed or if the first button is pressed (for example) the second and the third will not run at all? 
Alos, They must be defined inside my onCreate or could I define them outside,as a new function called CheckButtons(); and just call it from my on.Create() (or whenever else i want to check those buttons)?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with doing things this way. I can help more if you need it, but please clean up you question, it is near impossible to read.

Comment: Personally I think this is fine, obviously English isn't the first language bit it is still understandable, and more information has been provided than most questions on this site. You should write that as your answer @AedonEtLIRA by the way, I would upmark question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is correct. To go to the other screen, you do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherScreen.class);
startActivity(i);
```

and AndroidManifest.xml put permission for OtherScreen on tag Application:

```
 <activity android:name=".OtherScreen"> </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like you have it there is just fine. In the buttonclicked methods 1,2,3 you just need to start an intent to run the activity you want.

You need to change the id of each button though, R.id.Button01, R.id.Button02, R.id.Button03

Comment: They don't haaave to go outside. They can remain instance objects as they are now. I personally prefer it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting a little confused, edited my post about 4 times!

Answer (score 1):

you could try this... This is the easy way out though...

```
public class StackOverFlow extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    Intent i;

    b1= //get handle
    b2= //get handle
    b3= //get handle
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case b1:
        i=new Intent(StackOverFlow.this,destination1.class);
        break;

    case b2:
        i=new Intent(StackOverFlow.this,destination2.class);
        break;

    case b3:
        i=new Intent(StackOverFlow.this,destination3.class);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

}
```